# ASP.NET CORE Refused to frame 'https://app.powerbi.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, content-security-policy

I'm trying to frame a bi report in my ASP.net core application (currently run using IIS).

It works fine when ran in visual studio but when I try to run it through IIS I keep getting

> "This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.", with an error of
> "Refused to frame 'https://app.powerbi.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

I know I need to set a content security policy so I added this to my Program.cs file

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add(
        "Content-Security-Policy", 
        "default-src 'self'; https://app.powerbi.com/");

    await next();
});
```

but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: According to e.g. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) there is no semicolon `;` after the `'self'`. See also [the `frame-src` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src).

Comment: try to modify your code to `"frame-src 'self' https://app.powerbi.com/;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a Content Security Policy set in IIS. Adding another policy will only make the total policy stricter and not solve your problem. You need to identify how the existing policy is set and modify it. You either need to add app.powerbi.com to the self directive or implement the frame-src directive with this host.